# Google Page Speed Recommendation for Leveraging Browser Caching

Tags: firefox, caching, pagespeed

Well, I'm trying to optimize my application and currently using page speed for this. One of the strongest recommendations was that I needed to leverage browser caching. The report sent me to this page:

http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching

In this page there is this quote:

> If the Last-Modified date is
>   sufficiently far enough in the past,
>   chances are the browser won't refetch
>   it.

My point is: it doesn't matter the value I set to the Last-Modified header (I tried 10 years past), when I access and reload my application (always clearing the browser recent history) I get status 200 for the first access, and 304 for the reaming ones.

Is there any way I can get the behavior described in the google documentation? I mean, the browser don't try to fetch the static resources from my site?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better success using the Expires header (also listed on that Google doc link).

Also keep in mind that all of these caching-related headers are hints or suggestions for browsers to follow. Different browsers can behave differently.

The method of testing is a good example. In you case you mentioned getting status 304 for remaining requests, but are you getting those by doing a manual browser refresh? Browsers will usually do a request in that case.